# how to fix ajax call so i can hide my token?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

i'm calling a ajax function in html file in which i have integrated python django URL in which i have to pass token for get something so the problem which i am facing is my token is showing while i do inspect page source in html page. i want to hide it using java-script or ajax how can i do that please look at my code below.

```
$.ajax({
                        url         : url,                        
                        headers: {'Authorization': 'Token {{token}}'},
                        data        : card_data,
                        enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',
                        cache       : false,
                        contentType : false,
                        processData : false,
                        type        : type,
                        success     : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            console.log(data);
                            // Callback code
                            if(data['status'] == 'error') {
                                $("#lightbox").css({ 'display': "none" });
                                alert('error : ' + data['msg']);
                            } else {
                                    $('#lightbox').find('h1').text('Saved, redirecting you to products page');
                                    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'https://'+window.location.hostname+'/dashboard/destination/cards';}, 100);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: You can't hide anything on clientside. If you have secrets, do it serverside.

Comment: i.e. if a browser needs to use it, it needs to "see" it which means anyone can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to hide such information with JavaScript. You can try minifying your code so that your secret tokens are not easily discernible to the client-side.